# Initialize a char array after execution because size is initially unknown

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading

I'm writing a multi-threaded networking program. I need to declare a char array such that it can be seen by both threads. Only problem is that I don't know how big the array is going to be at first, since I have to wait for another computer on the network to tell me. The threads will already be created by the time I find out. It is vital that sharedBuffer be exactly the correct size.

Pseudocode below:

```
int bufSize;
char sharedBuffer[1]; //Ideally, sharedBuffer[bufSize]
                   //bufSize is not known yet, though.
                   //I don't know the best thing to declare here

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    pthread_t ThreadA;
    pthread_t ThreadB;
    pthread_create(&ThreadA,0,&funcA,0);
    pthread_create(&ThreadB,0,&funcB,0);
}

void *funcA(){
    bufSize = getSize();//getSize implementation irrelevant, but working
                        //Small numbers expected. Probably no higher than 1024
    //Initialize sharedBuffer here
    sharedBuffer = realloc(sharedBuffer,bufSize*sizeof(char));
    //Instinct tells me "sharedBuffer = new char[bufSize];"
    //    but I know C wont let me do that

    //semaphore post
}

void *funcB(){
    //semaphore wait (blocks until threadA posts)

    printf("Size of shared buffer: %d\n",sizeof(sharedBuffer));
    //needs to output bufSize
    //actual value is irrelevant. Data just needs to be shared correctly.
}
```

Edit: More information because no one seems to get my problem. I do not have a problem with timing and semaphores. Nor is there a problem with data being shared between threads. Nor is there a problem with thread creation.

My problem is that I don't know how to declare the shared buffer as an array type such that it can be initialized by one thread later, such that both threads can use it. I also don't know how to do the initialization.

Comment: An array is not a pointer (and vice-versa)!

Comment: `sizeof()` yields a `size_t` which is unsigned. In general, it is a bad idea to mix signed (`int`) and unsigned integers without need. You should use `size_t` throughout your code.

Comment: You can **never ever ever** use semaphores in multithreading apps sharing common memory between threads.

Comment: @SergeyA: I guess the manpage for `sem_init` is useless then: `If pshared has the value 0, then the semaphore is  shared  between  the threads  of  a  process,  and should be located at some address that is visible to all threads (e.g., a global variable, or  a  variable  allocated dynamically on the heap).`, since you're so sure about the "never ever".

Comment: @EOF, I was talking about different set of semaphore routines - the ones controlled with `semctl` and friends.

Comment: @SergeyA: Hmm, that doesn't sound like "never ever ever", that sounds like, "if you're unexpectedly (since you're using pthreads) using sysV semaphores in particular".

Comment: @EOF, to that I agree. I was too quick to jump to conclusion that OP is using those. Probably because this is a scenario I was dealing with the other day.

Comment: @Olaf I get that an array is not a pointer, but I don't know how to use the former properly. That's why I'm here asking for help.

Answer (score 2):

just do

```
char *sharedBuffer=NULL;
```

and

```
printf("Size of shared buffer: %d\n",bufSize);
```

your problem is that thread a allocates it. YOu need to defer threadB till threadA sets up the buffer. Or do some signalling / locking

Comment: The thread allocating it is not the problem, it is the goal. ThreadB IS deferred until ThreadA sets up the buffer. The problem is that I don't know how to make ThreadA do that. Your printf statement is not relevant to the problem I am trying to solve. bufSize is properly shared between the threads. The buffer itself is not.

Comment: i showed you how to do that, use a pointer not an array, rest is fine, realloc will do the alocate for you

Comment: realloc is not getting the job done. threadB is still seeing it as 8 bytes, no matter what size I realloc it to.

Comment: look at my second code line. sizeof(sharedbuffer) is a constant value (the size of a pointer). you must use bufsize

Answer (score 0):

```
char* sharedBuffer = (char *) malloc(bufSize);
```

Later use `free(sharedBuffer);` to release the memory when you are finished with it

Answer (score -1):

You can't `realloc` something which you didn't alloc with `malloc` first!. What you need to do is make your buffer a `char*`, and than `malloc()` it in first thread.

In the second thread you should use the size set by the first thread.

There is also a third, possible issue in your code. Depending on type of semaphores you use, they might not be suited for multithreaded environment. The ones you obtain with `semctl()` are the ones to avoid in such scenarios. The ones you get with `sem_init` are OK.

Comment: You can totally `realloc()` something you allocated by `calloc()`, or `realloc()`.

Comment: "There is also a third, huge issue in your code. Semaphores CAN NOT be used with multithreaded apps using common memory!" - Huh? Please elaborate what you mean!

Comment: @Olaf, SystemV semaphores (`semctl` and friends) are not suited for this. I guess, I was to quick to assume OP is using those.

Comment: ThreadB doesn't actually care what the size is. It just has to be able to see the array created by ThreadA.

Comment: @GregTheTraceur, what are you expecting to do with an array of unknown size?

Answer (score -2):

First of all, as your second thread is waiting for the first one to get the buffer size, you could invoke getSize() before starting the threads. After that you could then either:
1. Dynamically allocate the buffer which is in the file scope and have the threads a point to it.
2. Give each thread the buffer size and let them allocate their own buffers thus isolating the memory and remove the need to protect the memory with locks.

If you go with the first option, there are mutexes in the pthread library that you could statically allocate in the file scope or send a pointer to it in each thread to handle the synchronization.

Another issue is that you cannot realloc statically allocated memory, so you change it to a char* instead which you reassign with a pointer returned from malloc.
If thread B needs to know the size of the array and you go with option 1, then you should store this in a file scoped variable as well.

Comment: `sharedBuffer` is a static array. You cannot `realloc` a static variable!